# Bluetooth “out of band” (OOB) limitation for developers on iOS?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm generally curious what the reasons are why Bluetooth Out of Band is limited for 3rd party devs on iOS. It seem's like iOS is supporting it see Apple Watch pairing etc.

But why it's not public than for us?

Thanks you!